# Visual C++ Windows Forms Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I have written a C++ piece of code in Visual Studio. Now I have created Windows Form application in order to create user interface for my program (that is my task).

How can I use my calculated variables from cpp file in my header file? or should I try to rewrite the whole code in the header file (Im using different libraries for calculation and they are not working in header file)?

Sorry, If its a simple question, Im just a beginner.

Comment: I think the best option is to separate your calculation code from the user interface, to keep things better organized. So for example, you can create a "mycode.h", where you expose the variables and functions you need to use in your form, and a file "mycode.cpp", where you'll implement your calculation. Then, include "mycode.h" inside your form. I don't know if it answers your question, is that it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Will I be able then to use variables from mycode.h in my form.h?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Maybe you'll only need to put it inside a namespace, and refer to it in your form.h, I'm not certain. I don't usually work with C++.

Comment: I tried to do that but it gives me some errors. Can anybody show me how correctly connect code to user interface?

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on. Could you provide a minimal example of code and the compiler messages that you're getting?